# Can Pasch's axiom be derived from these postulates?

Tags: geometry

**Postulates**:

- Given any line, there are points on the line and points not on the line.
- Given two distinct points there exists a unique line passing through those points.
- Given three points on a line, one and only one of them is between the other two.
- Given two points $A$ and $B$ there always exists a point $C$ between $A$ and $B$ and a point $D$ such that $B$ is between $A$ and $D$.
- A line $m$ determines exactly two distinct semi planes, whose intersection is the line $m$.

**Pasch's axiom**: If a line not going through the vertices of a triangle (here I'm excluding the degenerate case of a triangle formed by three points on the same line) intersects one side, then it intersects another side.

Comment: Please define "semi-plane"

Comment: My foundations instincts are a little rusty, but the "semi-planes" postulate seems like a statement of the Plane Separation Axiom; the PSA [is known to be equivalent to Pasch's Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasch%27s_axiom#Equivalences), given an appropriate set of other axioms (say, Hilbert's). Off-hand, I couldn't say whether equivalence can be shown with the *particular* set of axioms you list. What's the context of this problem? A textbook exercise?

Comment: It is indeed a textbook exercise. Thanks for replying, I know now that the answer to my question is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered.